# INNER JOIN SQL query includes duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have an online store and am trying to display five similar products on the product page. There is a many-to-many relationship between products and tags which I'm trying to query (join table) using `INNER JOIN`. Here is the SQL query I have thus far:

```
SELECT TOP(5) *
FROM [Store_ProductTags] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [Store_Products] AS [s0] ON [s].[ProductId] = [s0].[Id]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TagId IN (1, 17) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

It does what I want (which is getting five products with the same tags as the product that is being displayed), however, includes duplicates...

This is the result I'm getting (notice the two records with the ProductId of 1):

```
ProductId   TagId       Name
10          17          Harlots - The Woman You Saw... (CD)
1           1           Unholy - Blood of the Medusa (CD)
44          1           Unholy - Blood of the Medusa (LP)
1           2           Unholy - Blood of the Medusa (CD)
2           2           Lye By Mistake - Arrangements for Fulminating Vective (CD)
```

I'd like to exclude duplicates. So far I've tried `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, as other response in different questions showed, to no avail. The error I receive when I add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` is...

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
> specified.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by product and sort the results by the number of matched tags:

```
SELECT TOP(5) p.Id, p.Name
FROM Store_Products AS p INNER JOIN Store_ProductTags AS s 
ON s.ProductId = p.Id
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Name
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN s.TagId IN (1, 17) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, you can move the logic to a subquery in the `order by` clause:

```
select top (5) p.*
from store_products p
order by 
    case when exists (
        select 1
        from store_producttags pt
        where pt.productid = p.id and pt.tagid in (1, 17) 
    ) 
    then 0 
    else 1 
end
```

This selects 5 products, and gives priority to those that own the 2 searched tags.

Comment: @gabenotgave: this query would take advantage of an index on `store_producttags(producid, tagid)`. You woud probably need to assess both solutions against your real data to find out which performs best. I would be interested to know!

Answer (score 0):

Your code can return five products that don't match any of the tags, if there are no such tags.  I don't know if that is a feature or a bug.  Based on the description of the query, it sounds like a bug.

You want one row per product id.  I am guessing you really don't need the matching tags.  If not, the simplest method is to filter out products that don't match using `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT TOP(5) sp.*
FROM Store_Products sp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Store_ProductTags spt
              WHERE spt.[ProductId] = s.[Id] AND
                    spt.TagId IN (1, 17)
             );
```

Comment: I actually intended to include products that didn't have the same tag if there weren't at least five. Otherwise, this solution definitely would work. Thank you! :)